# Ошибка при подключении к MySQL со Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Имеется ошибка, сервер работает нормально, но последнее время проскакивает эта ошибка очень часто, источников не нашел.

Tomcat 7 и MySQL 5.5 на одной машине, по этому с сетью проблем нету
у приложения, которое *очень* активно пишет и читает с базы, вопрос следующий, может эта ошибка быть из за того, что у базы заканчиваются Connections или в чем может быть?

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with
>   path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could
>   not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications
>   link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.] with
>   root cause java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Спасибо за внимание, благодарю за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед использованием в своем приложении вы должны рассмотреть вопрос об истечении срока действия и/или проверять достоверность подключения, увеличивая настроенные сервером значения для тайм-аутов клиента или используя свойство соединения [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/) `autoReconnect = true`, чтобы избежать этой проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Спасибо, сработало