# Не коннектится с базой данной

Tags: java

```
package dataBase;

import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Connector {

    static int lport;
    static String rhost;
    static int rport;

    public static void openSSH(){

        String user = "p583683";
        String password = "123";
        String host = "p583683.ftp.ihc.ru";
        int port=22;

        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            lport = 15000;
            rhost = "p583683.mysql.ihc.ru";
            rport = 3306;
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
            session.connect();
            int assinged_port=session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
            System.out.println("localhost:"+assinged_port+" -> "+rhost+":"+rport);
        }
        catch(Exception e){System.err.print(e);}
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            openSSH();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("An example for updating a Row from Mysql Database!");
        Connection con = null;
        String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://p583683.mysql.ihc.ru:3306/";
        String db = "p583683_max";
        String dbUser = "p583683_max";
        String dbPasswd = "123";

        try{
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db, dbUser, dbPasswd);
            try{
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                String sql = "UPDATE MyTableName " +
                        "SET email = 'ripon.wasim@smile.com' WHERE email='peace@happy.com'";

                int update = st.executeUpdate(sql);
                if(update >= 1){
                    System.out.println("Row is updated.");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Row is not updated.");
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException s){
                System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Не понимаю почему нет соединения, хотя сервер работает 100%. Через Navicat подключаюсь все нормально а из джавы никак.

```
Establishing Connection...
localhost:15000 -> p583683.mysql.ihc.ru:3306
An example for updating a Row from Mysql Database!
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:172)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:862)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at dataBase.Connector.main(Connector.java:59)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:59)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:103)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:149)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:165)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:92)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:982)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:852)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:173)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:66)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Если что-то с ходу предположить. А если цепляться к `localhost:15000`? Не для этого ли вы там какую-то магию с SSH и пробросом портов делали?

Comment: @mrEvgenX Соединение к серверу идёт через туннель SSH, порт 15000 для этого и прокинул. SSH соединение проходит успешно, а когда уже через jdbc пытаюсь то нифига. Или тут вообще не нужно через jdbc а сразу через jsch сессию запросы отправлять, я хз, первый раз такое делаю

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при подключении к Mysql со spring JdbcTemplate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883501/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba-mysql-%d1%81%d0%be-spring-jdbctemplate)